# Question about the algebraic definition of tangent space

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $V\subset \mathbb{A}^n(K)$ be an affine algebraic set and let $K[V]$ be its coordinate ring. For $a\in V$, let $T_aV$ be the tangent space of $V$ at $a$ and $P=I(a)$ be the maximal ideal in $K[V]$ at $a$. The homomorphism $\varphi:P\to Hom_k(T_aV,K)$ has kernel $P^2$.

I am reading a proof for this fact from page 106 of http://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/commalg-2013/chapter-11.pdf. To prove $ker(\varphi)\subset P^2$, we look at the linear space $L=\{d_ag | g\in I(V)\}$. Suppose it is of dimension $k$. Then why is the dimension of the zero locus of $T_aV$ equal to $n-k$?

Answer (score 0):

By linear algebra: the elements of $L$ are just $K$-linear morphisms from $T_aV$ to $K$, so to give an element there is to define the coefficients $(b_i)$ of your linear equation. In other words, you are giving coordinates with respect to the basis $y_1, \ldots, y_n$, which is the dual basis in $T_aV$ corresponding to the basis $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. I'm following the notation of the notes, but I'd prefer to write $dx_i$ instead of $y_i$, just to insist that they are forms.

Then, the zero locus of $L$ is the space of solutions of the linear system given by a set of independent generators of $L$, let's say $d_ag_1 = \sum_{j=1}^{n} b_{1j} y_j, \ldots, d_ag_k = \sum_{j=1}^{n} b_{kj} y_j$, and the dimension of this is $n$ (the number of variables) minus $k$. (The rank of the system, and here is $k$ because we took our generators independent)